# What is the maximum number of sockets that epoll can handle?

Tags: c, linux, epoll

I have used upto 1000 sockets in epoll. Is it possible to use million sockets in single epoll ? Is it efficient ?.

Comment: What have you done so far. have you tried google ?

Comment: "Yes", to both questions, as can be seen with a simple use of google.

Answer (score 2):

500,000 TCP connections from a single server is the gold standard these days. The record is over a million. It does require kernel tuning. See, for example, Linux Kernel Tuning for C500k. (https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1740823)

Comment: Those tunings are no longer needed, and can only hurt things, really. A million connections per node is nothing special these days. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike with `select()`, there is no intrinsic limit on the number of sockets managed by `epoll()`. So long as you don't hit any extrinsic limits on the number of sockets *in general*, like the maximum number of file descriptors in the system, or kernel memory, you can use as many sockets as you want with `epoll()`.